# @login_required not working as expected in Django?

Tags: django, authentication

I find `@login_required` very useful. I have used this `@login_required(login_url='/login/')` before each views. If the user tries to access `/upload` url it redirects to url as: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/?next=/upload_file/` My urls are very simple:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    #url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^upload_file/', 'fileupload.views.upload_file'),
    url(r'^show_file/', 'fileupload.views.show_list'),
    url(r'^sync/', 'fileupload.views.sync'),
    url(r'^login/', 'fileupload.views.login_user'),
    url(r'^upload_file_form', 'fileupload.views.upload_file_form' )
)
```

Now when the user presses login the page is redirected to nowhere. I am sure my url pattern is not correct. What am I missing? Thanks

**Edit**:

```
def login_user(request):
    errors = []
    state = "LOG IN"
    username = password = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username='username', password='password')
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                state = "You're successfully logged in!"
            else:
                state = "Your account is not active, please contact the site admin."
        else:
            state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."

    return render_to_response('login.html', {'state':state, 'username': username}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `fileupload.views.login_user` view needs to honor the `next` querystring parameter itself. This is built-in to Django's login view, but since you have rolled your own, you'll need to implement that functionality yourself.

Comment: Have a look at the way Django's view is implemented -- `django.contrib.auth.views`

Comment: I have specified next in my template as : <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" /> but same error.

Comment: Can you show your `fileupload.views.login_user` code? Do you process the `next` parameter in this view?